# Undefined method for ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I have several models, which are connected to each other:

```
class InsurerPayment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :insurer
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :contracts
end

class Insurer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :contracts
  has_many :insurer_payments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :insurer
  belongs_to :insurer_payment
end
```

When I do `commissions = current_company.contracts.pluck(:commission).sum` in my **insurer_payments_controller**, I get the sum of commission for all the contract related to my current company. But I need to get the sum of commission that belongs to insurers of my current company. Doing something like `commissions = current_company.insurers.contracts.pluck(:commission).sum` gives me an error: **undefined method `contracts' for # Insurer::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f92450f79c0**.  How can I get the result I need? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
current_company.insurers.map { |ins| ins.contracts.pluck(:commission).sum}
```

You are getting this type of error because when you hit **`current_company.insurers`** is return an array, and you hit **contracts** on this array this is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks alot, it helpped